# How to check Item exists in Firebase Database? - react-native-firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native, react-native-ios

Currently, I am using https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase for my project. I have a custom database for users and I want to check if the user exists or not by email.

Here is a screenshot of the database:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic firebase method but you may need to reconfigure the method to suit your data structure. Please refer to the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#equalTo) if you wish to know more.

```
firebase.database()
    .ref(`/users`)
    .orderByChild("email")
    .equalTo(email)
    .once("value")
    .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.val()) {
            // data exist, do something else
        }
    })
```

You can also query the registration status with `hasChild` method. Refer to your root path and query with `.once` and check the result returned.

```
export function checkUserExist(email) {
  return(dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/ExistingUser/`)
      .once('value', snapshot => {
        if(snapshot.hasChild(email)) {
          dispatch({
            type: FIREBASE_USER_EXISTED            
          });
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: FIREBASE_USER_NOT_EXISTED,
          });
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Another preferred method would be using the `fetchProvidersForEmail` method provided by Firebase. It takes an email and returns a promise that resolves with the list of providers linked to that email if it is already registered, [refer here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchProvidersForEmail).

Is there a good reason to store users credential in your database? In my daily practice, I would use the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` provided by Firebase for security purposes, [refer here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword). Just make sure rules are defined properly to prevent unauthorized access.